# discord.py remove roles from Discord bot

Tags: discord, discord.py, python-3.5

I want remove roles for user on command

```
 @bot.command()
 async def remove(ctx):
 guild = bot.get_guild('server_id') 
 role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id='role_id')
 await ctx.author.remove_roles(role)
```

But role not remove from user.

Comment: I think that is because the function body isn’t indented.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not indented right:

```py
@bot.command()
async def remove(ctx):
 role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id='role_id')
 await ctx.author.remove_roles(role)
```